# Imacros variable column with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

I am creating Imacros bot to submit site in the directory.
So I want to give {{!colN}} custom value
I have 2 CSV file, info.csv and category.csv files. 
In file.csv i am writing a custom number for example 3, and want to fill form with {{!col3}} from category

What I tried

1 - `{{!col{!col16}}` This isn't working

2

```
set !var1 {{!col16}}
SET !var3 EVAL("var r='{{!var1}}'; var x='{{!col' + r + '}}'; x;")
PROMPT Var_N:<SP>_{{Var_N}}_{{!Var1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:Address CONTENT={{!var3}}
```

This text writing {{!col3}} and not value from file

3)  I used some javascript and my site to get back value

```
macro += "tab open" + "\n";
macro += "tab t=2" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=http://example.com/email/gela.php/{{!col16}}" + "\n";
var url = window.location.pathname;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
macro += "tab close" + "\n";
macro += "tab t=1" + "\n";
```

But this code getting URL from the site where is was first. for example, home file is google.com and then redirect to example.com/email/gela.php/{{!col16}}
this code take value from google.com

Do you have any idea I am working on it for 3 days

Comment: ...................................

Comment: You may find a tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953779/if-else-imacros-with-javascript-command).